# SBL-EAI-04116:HTTP Internet Exception during 'Data Send': 'An error occurred in the secure channel support', code: '12157'

Tags: google-maps, ssl, google-geocoder, siebel, eai

**Integration Siebel - Google geocoding**:

the URL requests sent directly from the browser:

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Landsdorf%20Strasse,,Gr%C3%BCnewald,01945,Deutschland&key=API_key](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Landsdorf%20Strasse,,Gr%C3%BCnewald,01945,Deutschland&key=client's_API_key)

where API_key = particular API key provided by Google during first registration

Such request is working correctly, the response with geo codes is returned into the browser screen.

However if the same request is sent  via Siebel through BS: *EAI HTTP Transport*

The error is displayed:

> SBL-EAI-04116:HTTP Internet Exception during 'Data Send': 'An error
>   occurred in the secure channel support', code: '12157'.

Described solutions on official Oracle support Web  for that error are related to some missing certificate on external Server , (in our case Google Server)
This is a faily generic occuring at the Wininet layer during the SSL handshake.
And action should be: Throughly check the external webserver logs wih increased SSL tracing level on webserver.

but logically it does not make a sense, why URL request directly from the browser (same network) has been successfully sent and response was received
without using any certifications or similar stuff related to SSL handshake

Can someone help with it ?

Thank you
Best regards

Comment: Have a look at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67842936

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch here Siebel is sending data in UTF-16 format, and end point is rejecting it. Please check your outgoing trace messages.